# How mysql table size is calculated?

Tags: mysql

I'm not asking about the query.  I ran the following query

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME AS `Table`, 
       ROUND((DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH)) AS `Size (MB)` 
FROM  information_schema.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = "Books" 
ORDER BY (DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH) DESC;
```

I got following result:(calculated in bytes)

```
+------------------------+-----------+
| Table                  | Size (MB) |
+------------------------+-----------+
| BookOrders             |     16384 |
| BookRegistry           |     16384 |
+------------------------+-----------+
```

After adding 20 rows to the table also there is no increment in size for table?

So the size which is shown what it refers to?

How can I check for data storage size?

I used MongoDB where we can check the document size, collection size which I can track after inserting data

Comment: Tables, indexes, etc are stored in pages; blocks of data of fixed size.  If you don't fill up a page, it's still the same size on the disk.  Once a page is filled and a new page is required, then a new page is written to disk and the disk usage goes up.

Comment: Also, if there was some unused space in the table space, then that's going to be filled up. But this is not really a programming question and should have been asked on the DBA site.